# Displaying DateTime.Now in a String column within a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am not sure how to search this on Google so had to ask a question here.

I have a column for email body which is all text, but somewhere in text I want to display DateTime.Now, but not sure how to do it.

I want to put something in text like..

> "Hello User, Time now is {DateTime.Now}"

Don't want select statement or anything, must has to be value of column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select replace(all_text_column, '{DateTime.Now}', current_timestamp)
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(COL_NAME, 'your_placeholder', now())
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```